# Upload images to Google Drive without access to Google Play Console

Tags: google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

Is there another way to implement the Google Drive API instead of using the keytool to get the keystore sha1 and insert it into the Play Console credentials page? I'll use the APK outside the Play Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based from the documentation, the overall process of [making a Drive-enabled Android application](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started) is as follows:

> 1. Install the **Android SDK**.
> 2. Download and configure the **Google Play services SDK**, which includes the Google Drive Android API.
> 3. Register your application. To do this, you need to register a project in the Google API Console and get a signing certificate for
>      your app.
> 4. Add the **required settings** to your application's manifest.
> 5. Add Drive services to your application. The easiest way to begin is by **creating a file**.

There's no another way to implement Google Drive Android API other than the above steps. From step 3, you must register your application with the API console and run the **KeyTool utility** to get the `SHA1` fingerprint for your digitally singed `.apk` file's public  certificate. Then paste the `SHA1` to the credential page in the API console.